# OpenAI API Errors

Tags: openai-api

When testing my OpenAI API, I used the examples provided on the official OpenAI website. The **curl format** worked normally and output results, but the **Python format caused errors**. Even setting it as a system variable did not work. It still prompted this error: "**openai.error.APIError: HTTP code 401 from API (wrong api key)**". However, I could see in the **usage** that costs had already been incurred.

When I tried curl format like below:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -d '{
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt": "Say this is a test",
    "max_tokens": 7,
    "temperature": 0
  }'
```

I can get response successfully, but when I change to python format like:

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",
  prompt="Say this is a test",
  max_tokens=7,
  temperature=0
)
```

I can only get an error message "openai.error.APIError: HTTP code 401 from API (wrong api key)",although I have already set OPENAI_API_KEY as system variable and in Usage, costs had already been incurred

Comment: do you load your env with load_dotenv()?